# how to change booleanfield to use bootstrap switch toggle

Tags: django

I want to change booleanfield model to use bootstrap switch toggle.

```py
# model

blank_on_off = models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

[image]

If i click on the button like above, then *blank_on_off* which is false changes to true and if i click one more time then changes again false.

I think I should use JavaScript, how should I approach it? Thanks.

Comment: Have you created a model form? If yes, then js would be unnecessary.

Comment: @MoiMyazz really? Could you elaborate a little bit?

Comment: I have elaborated in an answer :-)

Answer (score 0):

You can create a model form to get it done as you wish without js. I just wrote a quick snippet.

In my **forms.py**:

```
class IdleForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = get_user_model()
        fields = ['is_staff', ]

        widgets = {
            'is_staff': forms.CheckboxInput(
                    attrs={"class": "form-check-input", "id": "flexSwitchCheckChecked"})
        }
```

Notice my widgets... I have the checkbox there and I have set the checkbox attributes of the bootstrap class **form-check-input** and the id **flexSwitchCheckChecked** and these will allow the checkbox to be styles as how you want it if bootstrap is available.

In my **views.py**:

```
class BlankView(TemplateView):
    template_name = 'dashboard/test.html'

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(BlankView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)

        context['form'] = IdleForm()
        return context
```

Finally in my **html** file...
You might want to copy [bootstrap starter template](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/getting-started/introduction/) to test this...

```
<!-- This is bootstrap's approach to get the switch -->
<div class="form-check form-switch">
    <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" id="flexSwitchCheckChecked" checked>
    <label class="form-check-label" for="flexSwitchCheckChecked">Checked switch checkbox input</label>
</div>

<!--This is our custom switch from the model form -->
<form>
{% csrf_token %}
    <div class="form-check form-switch">
        {{ form}}
    </div>
</form>
```

Image of my result here [image]

Answer (score 0):

Based on @Damoiskii's answer, here is how I got it to work on  a class based view using the `form-check-input` class on the Django form field:

**form.py**

```
from django import forms
my_boolean_field = forms.BooleanField(
    label="Some text for the frontend",
    widget=forms.CheckboxInput(
        attrs={
            "class": "form-control form-check-input",
        }
    ),
)
```

**template.py**

```
...
<div class="form-check form-switch">
  {{ form.my_boolean_field.label_tag }} {{form.my_boolean_field }}
</div>
```

Result:
[image: Django bollean field using bootstrap switch]